# How can I loop through attribute values and check if it contains a string

Tags: cypress

I have he following html code and would like to log the valueOfInterest:

```
<div id="123">
<span some-tag="valueOfInterest1">
<span some-tag="valueOfInterest2">
<span some-tag="valueOfInterest3"></div>
```

The following code does not work:

```
cy.get('div[id="123"] span').each(($el, i) => {
     const atri = $el[i].getAttribute('some-tag');
     cy.log(atri);
});
```

Sorry I am a beginner in Cypress... but what is wrong?
The error message above is: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined.
But that is only one of many solutions I tried. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To access attribute value you can use [Should()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should#Value)

```
cy.get('div[id="123"] span').each(($el, i) => {
     cy.get($el)
        .should('have.attr', 'some-tag')
        .then(attrValue => cy.log(attrValue))
});
```

Comment: In this case, eslint complains about "no overload matches this call ... ". However, the code works.

Comment: It is possible your ES lint is not configured to cypress.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is coming from the fact that you don't need to get the element with an index. Instead, the `$el` you are passing in is already the element you want.

```
cy.get('div[id="123"] span').each(($el) => {
    const atri = $el.getAttribute('some-tag');
    cy.log(atri);
});
```

Comment: In this case it says: $el.getAttribute is not a function.

Comment: Yep, I was mistaken. Look at @rosen's answer

Answer (score 0):

no need to use the index i, since the each loop does the job for you:

```
cy.get("#123").children().each((el)=>{
    cy.log(el.getAttribute('some-tag'))
})
```

Comment: You should avoid code-only answers. Answers that provide a rationale are much more likely to be helpful